# viewerjs downloads file instead of displays it

Tags: javascript, viewer

I'm using viewerJS to display files like .ODT and .ODS and facing strange behavior as it downloads the file instead of displays it inside the viewerJS.

Tried with PDF and it behaves correctly. File is displayed property. The only difference between different files is extension as files location and iframe setup is all the same. Tried in different browsers and its not the case.

Plase see below iframe setup:

```
<div id="wrapped_content">
    <iframe src="viewerjs/index.html../../../wrapped.odt" allowfullscreen="" webkitallowfullscreen="" ></iframe>
</div>
```

Have any body faced that issue?